# Changing temperature under adibiatic conditions?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, energy

Can a temperature change be adiabatic? For example if no 'heat' leaves or enters the system and we compress a fluid such that it's temperature changes is this still adiabatic? If energy is transferred via mechanical or electromagnetic energy (microwave) can we still determine the energy using:

$E=mc(T_2-T_1)$?

Can we still call this adiabatic?

Comment: To your first question, absolutely compressing a fluid in a chamber with perfect thermal insulation is adiabatic.  The second point about EM waves I would say no, if energy is transferred into or out of the system it is non-adiabatic, regardless of the mechanism.  Did you have a certain application in mind?

Comment: if energy is transferred and temperature increases not as heat, we can still determine the energy of the temperature change? Can we change the pressure without putting more energy into the system (Not done much thermodynamics yet)?

Comment: I'm not following what the first sentence means, "energy is transferred and temperature increases not as heat"... do you have a diagram or a specific scenario in mind (gas in a piston)?

Comment: my understanding of heat is that energy not transferred as work is heat into the system, so energy that transfers due to change of temperature, not a force acting on the system changing its energy so the formula $e=mc(t_2-t_1)$ can be used for energy transferred to increase the temperature regardless of whether its transferred from heat (like mixing two liquids or through conduction).

Answer (score 1):

Adiabatic means no heat transfer.

"Can a temperature change be adiabatic?" The ideal Otto cycle contains adiabatic compression and expansion, and the fluids in play heat up and cool down during compression and expansion.  So material can change temperature without heat transfer.

"If energy is transferred via mechanical or electromagnetic energy... Can we still call this adiabatic?"  No, because the definition of adiabatic is the lack of heat (energy) transfer.

> ad·i·a·bat·ic
> /ˌadēəˈbadik,ˌāˌdīəˈbadik/
> PHYSICS adjective
> relating to or denoting a process or condition in which heat does not
> enter or leave the system concerned. "the adiabatic expansion of a
> perfect gas"

Comment: Perhaps my definition of heat and work are incorrect, Heat is energy added to the system not through thermodynamic work, but a difference in temperature. so if there is work on the system not powered by conduction, convection or radiation it is not heat? But will change the internal energy, and hence the temperature, provided other state functions remain constant? Is this definition faulty, if so that makes sense then.

Comment: @user1007028 heat is the movement of energy between materials.  Heat flow is not a material heating up because you have done work to it (like compressed it, or run it through a pump).

Comment: so can we increase the temperature of a system by doing work on it with no heat flow in or out of the system? do

Comment: @user1007028 exactly